# 4 node(s) didn't match node selector k8s metrics-server

Tags: kubernetes, metrics-server

I just installed `metrics-server` on my kubernetes cluster running

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/download/v0.3.6/components.yaml
```

But the pod do not boot and I have the following error

```
0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metrics server have below `nodeSelector` in the deployment yaml

```
  nodeSelector:
    kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/arch: "amd64"
```

This error means that there is no node with label `kubernetes.io/os: linux` and `kubernetes.io/arch: "amd64"`

You can either remove the `nodeSelector` from the deployment yaml before deploying it or you can add those labels into your nodes.

```
kubectl label nodes <your-node-name> kubernetes.io/os=linux
kubectl label nodes <your-node-name> kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
```

Comment: Thanks,
I already have `beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux` and `beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64`

Comment: beta.kubernetes.io you have in the label but in the nodeselector it's looking for kubernetes.io